# Cannot access remote SQL Server from IIS 7 web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I've been trying to move the database from an application to another server without success.

I'm getting the following error message when opening the web application:

### "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."

The user is a domain user configured as identity in the app pool and also has full access rights on the SQL Server (I can access the DB remotely over SQL Server Management Studio).

I tried the following:

- enabled the **Do not require Kerberos preauthentication** option in AD
- added the SQL account to "Access this computer from network" Policy under Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Access this computer from network"
- Added the entry "127.0.0.1 localhost" to local hosts file

The domain user is local admin on the web and database server.

Web.Config / App Settings:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DBServer" value="remoteSQLDBHostName" />      -- previous: value="."
<add key="DBName" value="WebDB" />
<add key="DBProvider" value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add key="DBMetadataBase" value="res://*/{0}.csdl|res://*/{0}.ssdl|res://*/{0}.msl" />
</appSettings>
```

The connection string is build dynamically in the application (sample snippet):

```
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = serverName,
            InitialCatalog = databaseName,
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };

        var providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = providerName,
            ProviderConnectionString = providerString,
            Metadata = String.Format(metadataBase, Constants.ModelName)
        };

        var connStr = entityBuilder.ToString();
        return connStr;
```

Comment: post your connection string. Also, can you confirm that the AppPool user account being used is the one from the AD?

Comment: I added the app settings. Yes, the AppPool user is from the AD (DOMAIN\User in "Process Model\Identity" of the assigned AppPool)

Comment: I don't see what username/password/type of authentication the connection string is using.... At which point do you get this error within your code?

Comment: Does user has access right to database you are trying to connect on database server?

Comment: @PareshJ Yes, the user is configured as sysadmin and has access right to the database.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas The application uses "Integrated Security=True". I'm getting the error directly when opening the webpage (login page). It works fine with a local database.